# How to create constructor?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a scroll constructor so instead of having X amount of each functions for each page area to scroll I only want to create a "var" with properties (correct me if properties is the correct term to use).

Currently this is where I'm up to. I know I need to do something with the jQuery function inside the constructor but unsure how to format it.

```
function Scroll(button, scrollTop) {
    this.button = button;
    this.scrollTop = scrollTop;

    $(this.button).click(function () {
        $('html').animate({
            scrollTop: $(this.scrollTop).offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });

}

var top = new Scroll('#top', '.top-page');
var bottom = new Scroll('#bottom', '.bottom-page');
console.log(top);
Scroll(top);
```

Comment: You might find `this` been your issue, but here due to closures you could just remove them anyway.

Comment: holly crap it did work :D thanks

Answer (score 1):

You got an answer that worked, which is what really matters. But if you're still interested in the constructor paradigm, here's one way using the `class` syntax

```
class Scroll {
  constructor(button, scrollTop) {
    this.button = button;
    this.scrollTop = scrollTop;
  }

  static scroll(scroll) {
    $(scroll.button).click(function () {
      $('html').animate({scrollTop: $(scroll.scrollTop).offset().top}, 'slow');
    })
  }
}

const top = new Scroll('#top', '.top-page');
const bottom = new Scroll('#about', '.about-page');
Scroll.scroll(top);
Scroll.scroll(bottom);
```

I don't see this as any better than what you've done, just thought I'd answer the original question. That being said, since you're just going through and attaching a bunch of listeners, you could put all the button-scrollTop pairs in an array and just loop over those.

```
const scrollArr = [['#top', '.top-page'],['#about', '.about-page']];
for (let a of scrollArr) {
  $(a[0]).click(function() {
    $('html').animate({scrollTop: $(a[1]).offset().top}, 'slow');
  })
}
```

Then you don't have the additional lines with the `new` keyword.

Comment: thanks i will look into it, i wanted to learn about the constructor stuff hence my post.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Keith removing this. solved new code looks like this

```
function Scroll(button, scrollTop) {
    // this.button = button;
    // this.scrollTop = scrollTop;

    $(button).click(function () {
        $('html').animate({
            scrollTop: $(scrollTop).offset().top
        }, 'slow');
    });
}

var top = new Scroll('#top', '.top-page');
var bottom = new Scroll('#about', '.about-page');
```